# Make Phpfox default layout fluid width?

Tags: html, css, width, fluid, phpfox

Make Phpfox default layout fluid width?

Hi all.
I am using phpfox v 3.7.7 and I want my website to have a full width layout.

**Question:  How do I make the default phpfox layout fluid width?**  ...with a minimum screen width of 780px and a  max screen width of 1260px.  Please help me find the file(s) to edit and what code to enter.

Here is a link to a phpfox demo:  http://phpfoxmods.net/phpfox3/music/main/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override the `theme/frontend/default/style/default/css/layout.css` line 144 with `custom.css`